# How to guarantee MySQL lock acquisition order in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

We are using Rails 4.1 and we a model with a has_many.

Model X has_many Y

Y can be updated and will then update X through callbacks (increment a version field, modified_at, etc)

X can also be updated by itself.

This is causing deadlocks inside MySQL since one transaction will locked Y1 then want to lock X1 while another transaction will have locked X1 then want to lock Y1.

This is easy to fix by requiring at a minimum a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` on the owning X before updating a Y.

How do I do this in Rails? Or is there an even better solution?

I am considering trying to guarantee that I have a transaction in a before_update callback on Y and then acquiring a lock on X but I am not sure that will work well with Rails.

Comment: I recommend you avoid using callbacks. The really good approach to avoiding deadlocks is for every transaction to acquire row locks from tables in the *same order*. In your example, before updating a row in `Y`, acquire the lock on the parent `X1` row *before* you acquire a lock on `Y1`. Your transactions that updates only `X` will just get the lock on `X1`. By obtaining locks from tables in the *same order*, you can avoid a multitude of deadlock issues. To do that, you almost have to abandon AR callbacks.

Comment: Yes that is definitely a solution but a far from optimal one. I would like to absolutely minimize code changes required to remove these deadlock conditions. I seem to have success with adding in before_update callbacks to obtain all pertinent locks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `transaction` block?

So, for example, you can define your own `save_with_transaction` method as follows:

```
class X < ActiveRecord::Base
  def save_with_transaction
    transaction do 
      # multiple save, update, delete calls here ...
    end
  end
end
```

More documentation on transaction in ActiveRecord [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: We have a lot of code with different API controllers. I would like to find a way to modify only the model to guarantee the lock acquisition order. As in something through callbacks or patching active record.

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping your model Y & X update inside transaction.

```
X.transaction do 
 #Do Update on Y 
 #Update X
end
```

I haven't tested the theory in your particular case. But I think it should do the trick. Let me know if it works.